# Unity Android - Cant Build for x86_64 architecture

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, x86-64

I am trying to get a 64-bit build to comply with google play but whenever I "Analyse" my apk in android studio "x86_64"never seems to show up as a dependency under the "lib" folder.

Some details / things I've tried:

- Unity 2018.4.2f1 with gradle 3.2.0
- I am using "IL2CPP" as the scripting backend with ARM64 selected
- In the "defaultConfig" of my maintemplate.gradle I have manually specified the different archetectures with `ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64" }`

Answer (score 1):

According to the x64 integration docs,

> If you see armeabi-v7a **or** x86, then you have 32-bit libraries. If
>   you do not have any arm64-v8a **or** x86_64 libraries, you'll need to
>   update your build process
>   https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Unity3d Blog:

> While we added support for Android ARM 64-bit, we also reviewed the
>   usage of Android x86. Limited x86 Android devices were introduced to
>   the market which has resulted in minimal adoption of Unity’s x86
>   Android support. Android x86 support will be deprecated in 2019.2 and
>   removed entirely in Unity 2019.3. Support for Android x86 will
>   continue in Unity 2018 and 2018 LTS for the remainder of their life
>   cycle.
>   https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/

Also check this topic: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1630396/unity-build-for-android-x86-64.html